# How to combine data from different tables on the same Excel list in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 1 list of excel with different tables:

List1:

[image]

I want to unify them into one table in pandas. Could you advice me how to do it in pandas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: concatinate them `pd.concat(List1)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate the first sheet of some excel files, you can use the following code block:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  

## gets the first sheet of a given file
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
df.to_excel('total_sales.xlsx')
```

and if you want to merge various sheets of a given excel file in one pandas data frame, you can use the following code:

```
##gets all sheets of a given file
df_total = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:                         # loop through Excel files
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        sheets = excel_file.sheet_names
        for sheet in sheets:               # loop through sheets inside an Excel file
            df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name = sheet)
            df_total = df_total.append(df)
df_total.to_excel('combined_file.xlsx')
```

You can put your different tables in various sheets of one excel file or different excel files and then concatenate them using the above codes.

Comment: @nikita1221 you're welcome, hope this can help you to solve your problem. if this answer helps you, I appreciate your upvote!